# Angularjs : Validating modal elements without using form

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this modal which dont have form tag. But i want to validate all the elements inside before user proceed with clicking on any of these two buttons.

```
<div id="modal-invoice-member" class="modal fade" data-backdrop="static">
<!-- Modal Dialog -->
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal Content -->
    <div class="modal-content">

        <!-- Modal Body -->
        <div class="modal-body remove-padding">
            <!-- Modal Tabs -->
            <div class="block-tabs block-themed">
                <div class="block-options">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-option" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-toggle="tabs">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#modal-invoice-member-data"><i class="gi gi-user"></i> Member Details</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <!-- Account Tab Content -->
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="modal-invoice-member-data">

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-md-3">Name<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
                                <div class="col-md-8"  >
                                    <input type="text" style="text-transform: capitalize;" name="name" ng-model="user.name" class="form-control input" placeholder="First...  Last...  Middle..." required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-md-3" >Contact<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="input-group ">
                                        <input type="text" ng-pattern="/^[7-9][0-9]{9}$/" style="text-transform: capitalize;" name="mobile" ng-model="user.mobile" class="form-control digits" maxlength="10" placeholder="Mobile" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4" >
                                    <div class="input-group ">
                                        <input type="text"  name="email" ng-model="user.email"  class="form-control input" placeholder="Email" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-md-3">Gender<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
                                <div class="col-md-9" style="top:5px;">
                                    <label class="col-md-3" for="gender">                                
                                        <input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" ng-model="user.gender" value="F" required=""> Female
                                    </label>
                                    <label class="col-md-3" for="gender">
                                       <input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" ng-model="user.gender" value="M"  ng-checked="true" required=""> Male
                                    </label>
                                    <label class="col-md-3" for="gender">                               
                                        <input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" ng-model="user.gender" value="O" required=""> Other
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                    </div>
                    <!-- END Account Tab Content -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- END Modal Tabs -->
        </div>
        <!-- END Modal Body -->

        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit"  ng-click="saveMember()"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Save</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="addItem()"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Item</button>
        </div>
        <!-- END Modal footer -->

    </div>
    <!-- END Modal Content -->
</div>
<!-- END Modal Dialog -->
```

I want to all fields to get filled before user click on any buttons. Border color should get red when there is an empty element .
New idea also welcome .
Thank you

Comment: why wouldn't you just use a form and angular's built in validation? Can also use ngForm without an actual form tag

Comment: @charlietfl im new to this..idk how should i achieve this using ngForm .

Comment: By reading the docs and numerous angular form validation tutorials all over the web

Comment: See [AngularJS ng-form directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm), [AngularJS ngFormController API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController) and [AngularJS Developer Guide - forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms).